# Django - Override/Replace imports from 3rd part site-packages

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have upgraded my Django 2 to Django 3.

There is a package [django-jet](https://github.com/geex-arts/django-jet) which is not yet updated on Django 3.

So i am facing a import issue which is removed from django 3, so how can i changes/override/replace that single line from django package file.

```
File "/home/user/Documents/my_project/venv-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jet/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
ImportError: cannot import name 'python_2_unicode_compatible' from 'django.utils.encoding' (/home/user/Documents/my_project/venv-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/encoding.py)
```

I want to replace this line from package models.py file

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible
# replace with
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible
```

Comment: Fork `django-jet` repo, edit (remove `import python_2_unicode_compatible`, its usage as tag), build / install manually (or upload as different package to pypi). Django-jet (open-sourced) isn't updated since 2.1+, it may require changes, and it is easier to make them in fork.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling django-jet, and then installing django-3-jet -> https://pypi.org/project/django-3-jet/

1. pip uninstall django-jet

then

2. pip install django-3-jet

this worked for me